# setOnClickListener crashes the app - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imagebutton

I've 3 activity in my app. I set setOnClickListener on all the imagebutton in all the 3 activity. When I run the application and on clicking the first button in the first activity the app crash, but if I comment out `addListenerOnButton` code in the second activity the app works just fine. Any help is appreciated

This is the code of MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.caa;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton maschio, femmina;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        maschio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Uomo);
        femmina = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Donna);

        maschio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scelta_Simbolo.class);
                String genere = "maschio";
                i.putExtra("genere", genere);
                startActivity(i);

                /*SERVE PER VEDERE DIRETTAMENTE SU SCHERMO UN MESSAGGIO
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });

        femmina.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scelta_Simbolo.class);
                String genere = "femmina";
                i.putExtra("genere", genere);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pagina 1 - TEST"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Donna"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.826"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.661"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/woman" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Uomo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.793"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.238"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/man" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Voce_Uomo"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Voce Maschile "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.208"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.28" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Voce_Donna"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Voce Femminile"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.629" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is second class code: Scelta_Simbolo.java (without comment on setOnClickListener so in this case crash)

```
package com.example.caa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Scelta_Simbolo extends MainActivity {

    ImageButton si_no, su_giu, ok_nope;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scelta_simbolo);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        si_no = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.si_no_button);
       // su_giu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.su_giu_button);
      //  ok_nope = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ok_nope_button);

        Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final String receiveValue = receiveBundle.getString("genere");

        si_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
              /*  Intent i = new Intent(Scelta_Simbolo.this, Ripr_Audio.class);
                String scelta = "si_no";
                i.putExtra("scelta", receiveValue);
                startActivity(i);*/

            }
        });

/*        su_giu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(Scelta_Simbolo.this, Ripr_Audio.class);
                String scelta = "su_giu";
                i.putExtra("scelta", scelta);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        ok_nope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(Scelta_Simbolo.this, Ripr_Audio.class);
                String scelta = "ok_nope";
                i.putExtra("scelta", scelta);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

And the xml activity_scelta_simbolo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pagina 2 - TEST"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scegli quale tipologia di simboli vuoi utlizzare:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.149" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/si_no_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.336"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/si_no" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/su_giu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/si_no_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/si_no_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.531"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/su_giu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ok_nope_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/su_giu_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/su_giu_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.728"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ok_nope" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: change the function declaration to `public class Scelta_Simbolo extends AppCompatActivity ` and see if it solves your issue

Comment: Please post the log output from the crash since that is what is most likely to enable us to help you.

Comment: Please add the crash log.

Comment: @rcs Thanks it works! Can you explain to me what has changed? I thought that any other activity I create is an extension of the previous activity...

Comment: @AlessandroVazzola when you extend previous activities you inherit member variables as well which might have caused some nullpointerexception and may have crashed the app, so its always advisable to extend baseactivity like AppCompatActivity